# Commands to execute background process in Docker CMD

Tags: bash, shell, docker, dockerfile

I am creating a docker image using a Dockerfile. I would like to execute some scripts while starting the docker container. Currently I have a shell script to execute all the necessary processes

> CMD ["sh","start.sh"]

I would like to execute a shell command with a process running in background example

> CMD ["sh", "-c", "mongod --dbpath /test &"]

Comment: You can start the container as a background process using 

    `docker run -d {image}`

It that what you meant?

Comment: Hi I want to start a process inside docker container  as a background process . So Currently i am mentioning the same in a shell script file and creating a docker image . So when I run the docker image its  the process run as expected . But I wanted to instead of having a separate shell script file can I do it in the docker file using CMD command in Dockerfile

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Besides the comments on your question that already pointed out a few things about Docker best practices you could anyway start a *background* process from within your `start.sh` script and keep that `start.sh` script itself in *foreground* using the `nohup` command and the ampersand (`&`). I did not try it with `mongod` but something like the following in your `start.sh` script could work:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
nohup sh -c mongod --dbpath /test &
...
```

Comment: You could also give supervisord a try.

Comment: I also found the following link very helpful in describing how to prevent the necessity of starting background services in a docker container: https://runnable.com/docker/rails/run-multiple-processes-in-a-container

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is also the [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) of how to start multiple services, again using a script file not the `CMD`. The docker documentation also states how to use supervisord as a process manager:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY my_first_process my_first_process
COPY my_second_process my_second_process
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

If it is an option you could use a phusion base images which allows running multiple processes in one container. Thus you can run system services such as cron or other processes using a service supervisor like `runit`.

More information about whether or not a phusion base image is a good choice in your use case can be found [here](https://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/)

A ruby focused description of how to avoid running more processes in your container except for your app you can find [here](https://runnable.com/docker/rails/run-multiple-processes-in-a-container). The elaborations are too detailed to repeat on SO.