# How to run a shell script from docker image when we run that image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to dockerize my web application. In my docker file i'm pulling my code from gitlab, then installing node module in code container itself.
Once the image is created i'm trying to run docker image to create container in which i have to run a shell script as soon as i create container from image.

```
FROM alpine

LABEL MAINTAINER "CoE"
WORKDIR /

ARG proxy
ARG username
ARG pswd

RUN export http_proxy=$proxy                                                                    && \
    export https_proxy=$proxy                                                                   && \
    git clone -b master https://$username:$pswd@git.devops.company.net/dlr_ui         && \
    npm install                     

 EXPOSE 14001 14002 14003 14004 14005 14006 14007 14008
 WORKDIR /applications/package/ui_servers 
CMD [./startUIServer]
```

To Build:

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg proxy=$http_proxy --build-arg username=abcd --build-arg pswd=12123%4022121 -t ui2 .
```

then to run:

```
docker run -d -it -p 14001:14001 -p 14002:14002 -p 14003:14003 -p 14004:14004 -p 14005:14005 -p 14006:14006 -p 14007:14007 -p 14008:14008 --name=uistart ui2  /bin/sh
```

> It will create a container but it will we showing exited when i do

```
docker ps -a
```

when i check the docker logs by

```
docker logs
```

it will show nothing

> how to run that script so that all my UI server will up when i do docker run. I don't want to do `docker exec -it uistart /bin/sh` and then run the shell script manually.

Comment: Why do you pass `/bin/sh` as an argument to your run command?

Comment: to specify to run script ad sh which is present in /bin.

Answer (score 1):

> It will create a container but it will we showing exited when I do  `docker ps`

That means your script launching the server... does exit immediately.

Since that script is the main entrypoint of your container, if it stops and exit, the all container stops and exits.

You need to make sure your script launches the server, and then wait, as a main foreground process. (for example [using supervisor](https://blog.trifork.com/2014/03/11/using-supervisor-with-docker-to-manage-processes-supporting-image-inheritance/))

Comment: but i'm using nohup sh runorg1.sh > ../logs/org1_ui.log &   nohup sh runorg2.sh > ../logs/org2_ui.log    I don't think this should exit.

Comment: @ShalabhNegi try launching them as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/31571310/6309. But the best practice remains to use supervisord: https://advancedweb.hu/2018/07/03/supervisor_docker/

Comment: I have tried all this medthod but nothing worked:       CMD ["forever","start","Core.js"]
CMD ["./startUIServer.sh"]
CMD ["node","Core.js","org1","14001"]
CMD ["node","Core.js","org1","14008"]
CMD ["node","Core.js","org1","14004"]
CMD [./startUIServer.sh]
CMD ["/bin/bash","./startUIServer.sh"]

CMD ["sh","./startUIServer.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/sh /applications/package/ui_servers/startUIServer.sh"]
CMD sh ./startUIServer.sh
CMD [sh ./startUIServer.sh]
CMD ./startUIServer.sh
CMD /bin/sh ./startUIServer.sh
CMD ["nohup","sh","./startUIServer.sh"]
RUN ./startUIServer.sh

Comment: @ShalabhNegi I agree. Can you try with supervisor? (meaning it is supervisor which runs on foreground, launch any process you want, and wait)